# .changePage() changes page, but reloads previous page

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing phonegap application using jQuery Mobile. Below the code I have used to changes page when click on Button

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn_new_register', function (e) {
    $.mobile.changePage($("#newuserregister"), { transition: "slide"} );
});
```

My problem is when I click button it load registration page but within a second it load previous page (Login Page).

I have use single page structure using jQuery Mobile.

Please help me on this.

I have seen questions asked on the stack overflow but didn't find solution.